# Importing CSV file in NetLogo

Tags: csv, netlogo

I'm a new user of NetLogo and I'm trying to import the `CSV` format file in *NetLogo*. this is the geometry of a plan in Revit but unfortunately, I couldn't.the name of my file is `Window.csv`, and I tried different methods from this website and *NetLogo* dictionary.
I used NetLogo Extension:

```
set filename “C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.3\Window.csv”
to-report sum-columns [ file ]
  file-open file
  set result csv:from-row file-read-line
  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    let row csv:from-row file-read-line
    set result (map [?1 + ?2] result row)
  ]
  file-close
  report result
end
```

Thanks in advance.

I

Comment: Would you supply some more details? What have you tried? What, specifically, are you struggling with? Have you tried using the [CSV extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html)?

Comment: I tried to write this code from NetLogo Dictionary:                             to-report sum-columns [ file ]
  file-open file
  set result csv:from-row file-read-line
  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    let row csv:from-row file-read-line
    set result (map [?1 + ?2] result row)
  ]
  file-close
  report result
end

Comment: I don't know exactly, the step by step for importing CSV file.

Comment: Ah, that code uses the old NetLogo 5 task syntax rather than the new arrow syntax. I've now fixed it for the next version. You can find the fixed code here: https://github.com/NetLogo/CSV-Extension/. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I don't know which code I must use. I tried  csv:from-file "/path/to/myfile.csv" and changed the myfile with the name of  my csv file that is "Window" and I copied this line in NetLogo program in code space. Unfortunately, I couldn't solve it.

Comment: What is going wrong? Are you getting an error? Is it not behaving like you expect? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Firstly, Where must I put my csv file for importing in csv? (any specific folder in NetLogo installation program?) Secondly, when I copy this code:    csv:from-file "/C:/Program Files/NetLogo 6.0.3/to/Window.csv"  in observer, I see the error that  ERROR: Nothing named CSV:FROM-FILE has been defined.

Comment: Ah, I see. Put `extensions [ csv ]` at the top of your code. See here for how to use extensions in general: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/extensions.html. I recommend putting the csv file in the same folder as your model. Then you can load it just with `csv:from-file "Window.csv"`. That will load it as a list of a lists.

Comment: I did all steps one by one I put my model and CSV file in a same folder and copy this formula at code space  'extensions [csv]
globals [ data ]

to setup
  ca
 set data csv:from-file "example_data.csv"
  print data
  reset-ticks
end' but i didn't see the CSV data in code space.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I did all steps one by one I put my model and CSV file in the same folder and copy this formula at code space  <extensions [csv]
globals [ data ]
to setup
  ca
 set data csv:from-file "example_data.csv"
  print data
  reset-ticks
end> but I didn't see the CSV data in code space.

Comment: What does happen? That should work. Try running `print length data`. If that ends up empty, you might be accidentally working with an empty file or corrupt file.